# Is there a way to set path for docker build with the github action plugin docker/build-push-action@v1

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a docker build action as below

```
      - name: build-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          repository: <repo>
          tags: tag
          push: true
          dockerfile: ./<path-to-dockerfile>/Dockerfile
```

The dockerfile has instructions to ADD few files to the docker image as below

```
ADD file1 .
ADD file2 .
ADD file3 .
```

the structure of github is:

```
-.github
-folder1------------
                   |
                   folder2-------------
                                       |
               -----------------------docker--------
               |             |           |          |
            file1          file2        file3      Dockerfile
```

The issue is that the GitHub action is unable to find **file1**, **file2** and **file3** as it is looking in the level of **folder1**. The error generated is

```
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: file1: file does not exist
```

I do not want to modify the path in dockerfile as  `ADD ./folder1/folder2/file1 .`.
So how do I add path or change directory from the GitHub Action part using docker/build-push-action@v1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using docker/build-push-action@v1 use docker/build-push-action@v2 as v1 is an older version.
Modify the GitHub action as below

```
  - name: Login to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v1
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
  - name: build-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: ./folder1/folder2/docker/
          tags: tag
          push: true
          dockerfile: ./<path-to-dockerfile>/Dockerfile
```

using **context** with the github action will solve this issue. **Context** is available only with v2 verison.

Comment: seems to be only `file` now

Answer (score 3):

```
- name: Login to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v3
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
  - name: build-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: ./folder1/folder2/docker/
          tags: tag
          push: true
          file: ./<path-to-dockerfile>/Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      context: "{{defaultContext}}:subdirectory"
```

https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#git-context